# Is it possible with Delphi to create a static library for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, static-libraries, delphi-xe8

I would like to use existing Pascal source (no user interface) in an iOS app (Xcode project). So I need to create a static library, which I can then add to my iOS project.

Is there a way to create a static library (*.a) for the arm architecture within Delphi? Is there a compiler/linker option?

Or maybe there's another way to do this?

**Edit:**
I created a osx test project and used the library file from Dcp\OSX32 path and manually created the header file.

When I build the Xcode project I get the following error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Path/lib/testlib.a, file was built for
>   archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64):
>   /Path/lib/testlib.a

lipo says:

```
lipo -info /Path/lib/testlib.a  fatal error:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo:
> archive with no architecture specification: /Path/lib/testlib.a (can't
> determine architecture for it)
```

ar:

```
ar -t /Path/lib/testlib.a  
/  
//  
/1
```

The /Path/lib/testlib.a file was generated with a Delphi Package Project. The file seems not usable in an Xcode project.

Comment: I'm currently trying to solve same problem: compile legacy Delphi code as static or dynamic library to use in iOS application. Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Package_Static_Library_File) says that this is possible (with my emphasis).

> RAD Studio generates a package static library file:
>
> - **When you build a Delphi package for iOS Device or Android.**
> - When you build a Delphi package for a desktop platform and you use the "Generate all C++Builder files (including package libs)" value for
>     the C/C++ Output file generation option in Project > Options > Delphi
>     Compiler > Output - C/C++.
> - When you build a C++ package and you enable the Generate static package library (.lib) option in Project > Options > C++ Linker.
>
> A package static library file is a static library file generated from
>   a package. You use a static library in place of an import library when
>   your application does not use run-time packages. See Building Static
>   Packages.
>
> The file name of your package static library file is:
>
> - `<package>.lib` for 32-bit Windows.
> - `<package>.a` for 64-bit Windows and Mac OS X.
> - **`lib<package>.a` for iOS Device and Android.**

Comment: Thanks, the library was generated. But to use it in Xcode I still need a header file. Can Delphi create that?

Comment: I do not believe that it can. I think you have to do that manually.